# No image is shown in PHP from MySqL

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am trying to display an image from my php page by saving the image in the database [MySql] and when I retrieve it it did't show me the image. 
However, I can see the image when I click on it in MySql, but it is not shown in the php file.

Images Table: 
id INT

### image BLOB

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Uploade an image</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="test_image.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        File: 
        <input type="file" name="image"> <input type="submit" value="Uploade">
    </form>

<?php
mysql_connect("", "", "")
or die("<p>Error connecting to database: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");

mysql_select_db("test")
or die("<p>Error selecting the database: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");

// file propoerties
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if(!isset($file))
    echo "Please select an image.";
else 
{
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])); 
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    if($image_size == FALSE)
        echo "That's not an image";
    else
    {
        if(!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Images (image) VALUES ('$image')"))
            echo "Problem uploading image.";
        else
        {
            $lastid = mysql_insert_id(); 
            echo "Image uploaded <p /> Your image: <p /> <img  width='500' height='500'  src=getimage.php?id=$lastid>";
        }
    }
 }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

getimage.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("", "", "")
or die("<p>Error connecting to database: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");

mysql_select_db("test")
or die("<p>Error selecting the database: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");

$id = addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);

$image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Images WHERE id = $id");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image = $image['image'];

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

echo $image;
?>
```

I can upload the image but I can't retrieve it!!

Thank you,

Comment: First off, I'd recommend you switching to something else than mysql (Try out mysqli or PDO). Mysql is deprecated.

Comment: what output do you get exactly from the getimage.php script? try to save the image blob as base64_encode (and use base64_decode in the getimage.php script)

Comment: I can't switch now !! And I get a small question mark instead of the image. How can I save it as base64??

Comment: @FinalProject It's not hard to migrate and there are even [official tools](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi) to do it. You should really switch to MySQLi, as the basic MySQL extension is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use img html element to view the image

for example
src here is where you are saving your image file

```
<img src="images/yoursavedimagenameindatabase" width="" height="">
```

Then you can view your saved images in view

Comment: please debug your code and let me know what is the error you are getting so that i can help you

Answer (score 0):

```
$path="images/.$image['image']."    
echo '<img width="100" height="66"  src="'.$path.'" />';
```